# Get ID and Name Autocomplete JQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I can`t find the way to get the ID of my element when you search in the autocomplete textbox: I have this in mi HTML:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

      $(function() {
        $( "#local" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'buscar_local_nombre.php'
        });
      });
```

And this is "buscar_local_nombre.php":

```
<?php
  $dbHost = 'localhost';
  $dbUsername = 'root';
  $dbPassword = '';
  $dbName = 'restofinder';
  //connect with the database
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

  //get search term
   $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

   //get matched data from table
   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM locales WHERE NOMBRE LIKE  '%".$searchTerm."%' AND ESTADO = 1 ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC");
   while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
     $data[] = $row['NOMBRE'];
  }

   //return json data
     echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

How could I get ID too (hidden) so that i can store it in a variable and use it afterwards?

Thank you very much!

Comment: put id in a hidden input field and on change of the name through autocomplete update that hidden field value accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use `select`

```
$(function() {
     $( "#local" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'buscar_local_nombre.php',
        select: function (event, ui) {
           $("#hdnId").val(ui.item.id);//Put Id in a hidden field
        }
     });
});
```

**Reference**

- [Autocomplete get id as selected label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683051/jquery-autocomplete-get-id-as-selected-label)
- [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)
- [Autocomplete select name and display id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871869/jquery-autocomplete-select-name-and-display-id)